# Are there events in c++?

Tags: c++, events, c++-cli

I have a situation where the simplest answer would be a .net style event. I have never used events in c++ though and was under the impression that it didn't even have any. Regardless, I found this msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2k0a7d.aspx and tried following its example adding

```
[event_source(native)]
```

to the top of my class and

```
__event void fileChanged(std::wstring fileName);
```

as a public member but it won't compile and gives me the error  "Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding" which i don't even know what it means or what __try has to do with anything (since i don't have any try blocks in the class if thats what its referring to). And object unwinding? wat.

Comment: No, there aren't such concepts in 1st place, but several standard mechanisms that provide easily to build such.

Comment: hm... maybe it's nothing but try to change `std::wstring` to `std::string`

Comment: you may try the inotify API

Answer (score 1):

Your MSDN page tells you that there are events in C++. The example on that page compiles and works properly. This makes me think that it is having problems with the specific event that you are trying to set up.

So the next thing I'd do is to look at the MSDN page for the error: [C2712](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28C2712%29;k%28VS.ErrorList%29&rd=true)

This page states that this error can occur when using the `__event` keyword and you pass an argument by value (see link for exact description). Indeed, changing the call to a constant reference causes the error to go away:

```
__event void fileChanged(const std::wstring& filename);
```